# WPF textbox insert control characters such as tab, newline, or return

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set up a WPF TextBox, so that it displays control characters that are passed to it through binding?

For example, if I have the test string `"Start\\tafter tab\\rafter return"`, and I bind the `Text` property of the TextBox to this, how can I get it to display with the tabs and returns?

I should note the TextBox has `AcceptsReturn="True"` and `AcceptsTab="True"`.

Comment: Do you put this string in xaml?

Comment: no, the string is being pulled from the code-behind, through data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single `\t` instead of `\\t`.

```
TextBox.Text = "Start\tafter tab\rafter return";
```

Double `\\t` doesn't transform to tab, it transforms to `\t`.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: If that's it, you should mark his answer as the correct answer.

Comment: @TonyVitabile rather than stare at the screen for 8 minutes waiting for the required time to elapse before I could mark an answer as "accepted," I chose to do something more productive and get back to this. But thanks for your concern :-P